# JavaScript Node.normalize() behavior or bug?

Tags: javascript

Is the following a correct JavaScript behavior or a JavaScript engine bug?

```
var a = document.createTextNode('a');
var b = document.createTextNode('b');
var foo = document.createElement('foo');
foo.appendChild(a);
foo.appendChild(b);
foo.normalize();
console.log(a.textContent);
```

I would have expected this to log "a", but normalize() changes the initial child text node of foo, so it logs "ab" instead (at least in Firefox and Chrome).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the expected behavior. Quoting from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.normalize):

> Puts the specified node and all of its subtree into a "normalized"
> form. In a normalized subtree, no text nodes in the subtree are empty
> and **there are no adjacent text nodes**.

The precise process is [specified here](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-node-normalize) (thanks to *icktoofay* for the reference):

> For each `Text` node descendant of the context object:
>
> 1. Let *node* be the `Text` node descendant.
> 2. Let *length* be *node*'s `length` attribute value.
> 3. If *length* is zero, remove *node* and continue with the next `Text` node, if any.
> 4. Let *data* be the concatenation of the data of *node*'s contiguous `Text` nodes (excluding itself), in tree order.
> 5. Replace data with node *node*, offset *length*, count 0, and data *data*.
> 6. Let *current node* be node's next sibling.
> 7. While *current node* is a `Text` node:
>
>    1. For each range whose start node is *current node*, add *length* to its start offset and set its start node to *node*.
>    2. For each range whose end node is *current node*, add *length* to its end offset and set its end node to *node*.
>    3. For each range whose start node is *current node*'s parent and start offset is *current node*'s index, set its start node to *node* and its start offset to *length*.
>    4. For each range whose end node is *current node*'s parent and end offset is *current node*'s index, set its end node to *node* and its end offset to *length*.
>    5. Add *current node*'s `length` attribute value to *length*.
>    6. Set *current node* to its next sibling.
> 8. Remove *node*'s contiguous `Text` nodes (excluding itself), in tree order.

So yes, the specified behavior is to mutate the first text node found in the continuous set of text nodes and remove the subsequent ones.

Comment: The standard does look like it describes mutating the first child node. Thanks!